# convert date to week and count the dependencies from different columns of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
date            Company      Email

2019-10-07       abc         mr1@abc.com
2019-10-07       def         mr1@def.com
2019-10-07       abc         mr1@abc.com
2019-10-08       xyz         mr1@xyz.com
2019-10-08       abc         mr2@abc.com
2019-10-15       xyz         mr2@xyz.com
2019-10-15       def         mr1@def.com
2019-10-17       xyz         mr1@xyz.com
2019-10-17       abc         mr2@abc.com
```

I have to create 2 dataframes like this:

dataframe 1:

```
Weeks                      abc         def       xyz

octoter7-october14         3            1         1
october15-0ctober22        1            1         2
```

and dataframe2: Unique count for Emails as well weekwise

```
Weeks                      Company   Email_ID       count 

octoter7-october14          abc      mr1@abc.com     2
                                     mr2@abc.com     1

                            def      mr1@def.com     1

                            xyz      mr1@xyz.com     1

october15-october22         abc      mr2@abc.com     1

                            def      mr1@def.com     1 

                            xyz      mr1@xyz.com     1
                                     mr2@xyz.com     1
```

Below is the code what i tried to create `dataframe1` :

````
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date']) - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
df1 = df1.groupby(['Company', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-MON')])['Email_ID'].count().sum().reset_index().sort_values('Date') ```
````

````
               Company       Date                                           Email_ID
               abc         2019-10-07               mr1@abc.com.mr1@abc.com.mr2@abc.com                          
               def         2019-10-07                              mr1@def.com     
               xyz         2019-10-07                             mr1@xyz.com
               abc         2019-10-15                             mr2@abc.com
               def         2019-10-15                             mr1@def.com
               xyz         2019-10-15                           mr1@xyz.com.mr2@xyz.com ```
````

Here the sum is concatenating Email_ID strings instead of numerical counts and not able to represent my data as I want in `dataframe1` and `dataframe2`

Please provide insights on how i can represent my data in as dataframe1 and dataframe2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Grouper` need datetimes, so format of datetimes is changed by [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) after aggregation and also added `closed='left'` for left closing bins:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date']) 


df2 = df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-MON', closed='left'), 
                   'Company', 
                   'Email'])['Email'].count()

new = ((df2.index.levels[0] - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')).strftime('%B%d') + ' - '+  
        df2.index.levels[0].strftime('%B%d') )
df2.index = df2.index.set_levels(new, level=0)

print (df2)
date                   Company  Email      
October07 - October14  abc      mr1@abc.com    2
                                mr2@abc.com    1
                       def      mr1@def.com    1
                       xyz      mr1@xyz.com    1
October14 - October21  abc      mr2@abc.com    1
                       def      mr1@def.com    1
                       xyz      mr1@xyz.com    1
                                mr2@xyz.com    1
Name: Email, dtype: int64
```

For first DataFrame use `sum` per first and second levels and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df3 = df2.sum(level=[0,1]).unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df3)

Company                abc  def  xyz
date                                
October07 - October14    3    1    1
October14 - October21    1    1    2
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael can we fix the starting date of the of week as we want to? lets say 7th october was monday and next monday was 14th so i can arrange my data from one monday to another monday so next week starts from 15th

Comment: True that. My mistake, the week I am trying to set is from Tuesday to Monday

Comment: There seems to be some error because of date when I am manually counting there is mismatch

Comment: U can also see here in the above data that from oct7-14 'abc' count is 3 here getting 2

Comment: @SachinKumar - Answer was completely changed, change order in `new`, changed `pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-MON', closed='left')`

Comment: Yes  the closing was required I realized later after looking at the documentation

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a column that maps the date to a week
2. Do something with grouping: i.e. `df.groupby(df.week).count()`